# NodeJS & MongoDB - Can't send a parameter using a form to be later used in a mongoDB search

Tags: node.js, mongodb, forms, express, search

I am working on a shopping cart project in NodeJS & MongoDB, and I'm trying to make a search bar in my shop page.

*index.hbs*

```
    <form action="/" method="get" id="query-form">
        <input class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-offset-3" 
    type="text" id="query" name="query">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Search</button>
    </form>
    </div>
    {{# each products }}
    <div class="row">
        {{# each this }}
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="{{ this.imagePath }}" alt="..." class="img- 
    responsive">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>{{ this.title }}</h3>
                        <p class="description">{{ this.description }}</p>
                        <div class="clearfix">
                            <div class="price pull-left">${{ this.price }} 
    </div>
                            <a href="/add-to-cart/{{this._id}}" class="btn 
    btn-success pull-right" role="button">Add to Shopping Cart</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
    {{/each}}
```

When I send the information back, while trying to catch the result using a "route", I can't seem to be able to pass this "query" to be search in mongoDB:

*index.js*

```
    var successMsg = req.flash('success')[0];
    if(req.query.query) {
        let query = "/" + req.query.query + "/";
        Product.find({title: {$regex: query,'$options': 'i'}},function (err, 
    docs) {
            let productChunks = [];
            let chunkSize = 3;
            for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i += chunkSize) {
                productChunks.push(docs.slice(i, i + chunkSize));
            }
            res.render('shop/index', {title: 'Shopping Cart', products: 
    productChunks, successMsg: successMsg, noMessages: !successMsg});
    })
    }
    else
    {
        Product.find(function (err, docs) {
            var productChunks = [];
            var chunkSize = 3;
            for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i += chunkSize) {
                productChunks.push(docs.slice(i, i + chunkSize));
            }
            res.render('shop/index', {title: 'Shopping Cart', products: productChunks, successMsg: successMsg, noMessages: !successMsg});
        });
    }});
```

While debuuging, it seems that the route is being requested twice, and that in the last time it has no "req" object to use, hence there is no search.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: looking at your form `req.query.query` should probably be `req.body.query`

Answer (score 0):

If using `$regex` query operator explictly there is no need to append/prepend with `/` like that because then it would be string with `/` and not regular expression. `$regex` is going to make it into a regular expression while evaluation.

- Interestingly you're using `GET` with form (that's okay for search), Make sure `req.query` is coming to the route with `query` field (a valid string)

Simply pass the string to regex operator:

```
/*GET params in express go in req.query only*/
const queryToSearch = req.query.query;
Product.find({title: {$regex: queryToSearch,'$options': 'i'}});
```

- On request being called twice:

It should be an `OPTIONS` request usually known as `pre-flight request` is an intended behaviour from sources like: browsers. [Read More](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS)